# Fail to free memory in a mergeSort function

Tags: c, memory

I tried to write a mergeSort function in C.
In the function, I have pointers `a` and `tmp`; their value is different. However I fail to free the memory pointed by tmp.

(I write it with VS2013 in a `.cpp` file, Windows 10)

[breakpoint result before I run the free function.bmp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6Ryl.png)

```
inline int min(const int x, const int y)
{
    return x < y ? x : y;
}

void mergeSort(int array[], int len)
{
    len--;   //index:   0 ~ len-1
    int *a = array;
    int *tmp = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*len);

    for (int seg = 1; seg < len; seg += seg)
    {
        for (int start = 0; start < len; start += seg+seg )
        {
            int k = start;
            int start_1 = start;
            int end_1 = min(start_1 + seg-1, len);
            int start_2 = end_1+1;
            int end_2 = min(start + seg + seg-1, len);
            while (start_1 <= end_1 && start_2 <= end_2)
            {
                tmp[k++] = a[start_1] < a[start_2] ? a[start_1++] : a[start_2++];
            }
            while (start_1<=end_1)
            {
                tmp[k++] = a[start_1++];
            }
            while (start_2 <= end_2)
            {
                tmp[k++] = a[start_2++];
            }
        }
        int *t = a;
        a = tmp;
        tmp = t;

    }
    if (a != array)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= len; i++)
        {
            tmp[i] = a[i];
        }
        tmp = a;
    }

    free(tmp);  // fail to free pointer tmp in mergeSort function ??

}
```

Comment: Note that if you are writing in C, the extension for the source files is `.c` and not `.cpp` — the `.cpp` extension indicates C++ code.  Be careful with your tagging, too.  You say you're writing in C; don't tag your question with C++.  You will often get down-votes if you tag with both languages.  Thank you for including the platform and compiler information — that is helpful.

Comment: The natural solution to your problem would differ quite a lot depending on language. Please make sure that you're always tag the correct language you're actually programming in.

Comment: Thou shalt not cast the result of `malloc()`!

Answer (score 3):

When you assign to `tmp` (e.g. `tmp = a` or `tmp = t`) then you lose the original pointer.

If `a` isn't allocated with `malloc` then passing the new pointer to `free` will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

As for a possible solution, keep a copy of the original pointer that you can pass to `free`.

Comment: I understand what you said and tried it. `int* backup = tmp; ... free(backup);` fail again.At last, i found that my `malloc( len * sizeof(int))` memory is wrong. it should be `malloc(len+1 * sizeof(int))`.

Comment: Because I decrese it `len--`below。But if I did not malloc enough memory and i access the memory in the middle of function, the IDE did not throw a exception???

Comment: @LydonZ C have no bounds-checking, accessing memory out of bounds leads to undefined behavior. And one of the possibilities of UB is that it might seem to work fine, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning a new value to tmp here:

`tmp = t;`

Hence tmp loses its original value which points to the allocated memory location and now points to another memory not allocated using malloc. So you are unable to free it using `free()`